# Links with and without the .aspx extention

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, url-rewriting, iis-6

Is is possible to configure a server to allow using links with and without using the .aspx extention.

If yes, how could I go about setting this up.

I'm working on a client site who is using umbraco. I know it has built in friendly URL capibility. Unfortunatly the site is already live and turning the feature on for the whole lot of links.

The problem is they want to use promotional urls like www.sitename.com/promotion without having to append the .aspx extention. And we don't want to go through the trouble of enabling url rewriting site wide and having to track down all the broken links.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to accomplish?

Comment: I answered your question in my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Scott Guthrie has a good post on this.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before by writing a simple HttpModule, a couple things to note:

- You need to point 404 errors in IIS to an aspx page, otherwise IIS won't invoke the ASP.NET runtime and the HTTPModule will never hit.
- This works best to catch and redirect from vanity urls, not as a full featured urlrewrite.

```
    public class UrlRewrite : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
            application.BeginRequest += (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
        }

        private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            // The RawUrl will look like:
            // http://domain.com/404.aspx;http://domain.com/Posts/SomePost/
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Contains(";")
                && HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Contains("404.aspx"))
            {
                // This places the originally entered URL into url[1]
                string[] url = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.ToString().Split(';');

                // Now parse the URL and redirect to where you want to go, 
                // you can use a XML file to store mappings between short urls and real ourls.

                string newUrl = parseYourUrl(url[1]);
                Response.Redirect(newUrl);
            }

            // If we get here, then the actual contents of 404.aspx will get loaded.
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Needed for implementing the interface IHttpModule.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Half way down under the section **Completely Controlling the URI** provides links and a number of methods of accomplishing this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/bags/archive/2008/08/22/rest-in-wcf-part-ix-controlling-the-uri.aspx